# How to get a list of all foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys, flask-sqlalchemy

I'd like to get a list of all foreign keys in `SQLAlchemy` or `FlaskSQLAlchemy` - with their names - defined in my db. Preferably grouped by the tables they are defined in.

I only found one thing that's somewhat in relation what I am looking for:

```py
from sqlalchemy_utils import get_referencing_foreign_keys

for table, fks in group_foreign_keys(get_referencing_foreign_keys(User.table)):     ...:     
    print(table, fks)

documents <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f0bd6c3b070> 
entries <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f0bd6c3b6a0> 
histories <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f0bd6c3b070> 
requests <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f0bd6c3b6a0>
user_partner_relationships <itertools._grouper object at 0x7f0bd6c3b070>
```

But this only returns other table names which have a foreign key to the provided table. Not the foreign keys of the actual table. If I iterate through my tables with this I may be able to group the foreign keys with some further scripting.

But even after that I'd miss their names.

Is there any solution to get them with names?

Comment: perhaps https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/reflection.html#sqlalchemy.engine.reflection.Inspector.get_foreign_keys

Answer (score 1):

So following Gord Thompson's tip and update, I managed to do this:

```py
from sqlalchemy import inspect
from app import db # a flask_sqlalchemy SQLAlchemy object

inspector = inspect(db.get_engine()) # or the native SQLAlchemy engine you have

for table in inspector.get_table_names():
    print(table, inspector.get_foreign_keys(table_name=table))
```

This gets me exactly what I needed in a:

```
tablename ['''foreign_key_data''']
tablename ['''foreign_key_data''']
tablename ['''foreign_key_data''']
...
```

format.

Comment: FYI, the preferred form is `from sqlalchemy import inspect` and `whatever_name = inspect(engine)`.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the solution. Is it preferred because it's a "lighter" import?

Comment: Basically, yes.